# creating reference to a constant variable in C++

Tags: c++, reference

**compiler says invalid initialization at *line 3***
 I guess creating reference to *i*, it is telling the compiler that someone wants to change *i*, I guess this thing came with newer versions of the compilers because i have found this code in most of the books.

```
int main(){
 const int &i=10;
 int &j=1;
 cout<<j;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I am guessing this `const &i=10;` is supposed to be `const int &i=10;`? Besides that you need to make it a reference to a `const` like this `const int  &j=1;`.

Comment: Your code is ill-formed.  But what is your question?

Comment: yeah of course its *const int &i=10;*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides missing an `int` in `const &i=10;` the issue with the next line is that you are creating a reference that is not `const` (i.e. which allows what it refers to to be changed) and the number `1` is a *constant*. You'd encounter the same problem with the following code:

```
const int i = 1;
int &ri = i;
```

It should be obvious why.

Comment: I think 'It should be obvious why,' is not accurate. For example `int &&j=1;` is perfectly valid. VC++ has a non-standard extension that allows `int &i=1;` as well. There's no technical reason that prevents compilers from doing this, its simply that the language explicitly prohibits non-const lvalue references from binding to rvalues.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
int &j=1;
```

Is not valid, because you're creating a non-const reference (which would allow you to modify the referent) from a constant value (which cannot be modified, for obvious reasons).

Do this instead:

```
const int &j=1;
```

Also, the line that declares `i` makes no sense.  Just delete it.

Comment: I think 'for obvious reasons' is not accurate. For example `int &&j=1;` is perfectly valid, and VC++ has a non-standard extension that allows `int &i=1;` as well. There's no technical reason that prevents compilers from doing this, its simply that the language explicitly prohibits non-const lvalue references from binding to rvalues.

Comment: yeah, i got this code as it is in a book, but of course they might be just assuming something..